# When to use Google AMP HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I am in a confusion to use [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org) HTML or not?

The site is online hotel booking website.
site includes Dynamic banners, image popup, Ajax forms in all pages to calculate price for selected hotel. We are using fullcalendar, daterange-pickers, other js libraries. 
Complete site is responsive using Boostrap.
The content(availability, info) in the site will changes every hour.

From AMPproject:

> AMP files can be cached in the cloud in order to reduce the time
>   content takes to get a user’s mobile device. AMP HTML comes with
>   strong limitations on JS. With this in mind we made the tough decision
>   that AMP HTML documents would not include any author-written
>   JavaScript, nor any third-party scripts.

Question:
 Is site still works as before(without AMPhtml) After migrating to AMPhtml?

Any information will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In short no your site does not sound like a good fit for AMP.

AMP is currently intended primarily for static pages (news articles and blog postings) and won't allow javascript except those used by AMP. It therefore is a poor fit for a dynamic site such as yours. Bootstrap, AJAX calls, date pickers and other JS will not work so it's unlikely you could get your site to work with AMP at all.

Suggest you read up more on it.